# Cast static array to pointer in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi

Recently when using Delphi arrays, I encounter some problems which make me consider them more carefully.

I write a test function:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyArray1: array[0..0] of UInt64;
  MyArray2: array of UInt64;
  Value1, Value2: UInt64;
begin
  SetLength(MyArray2, 1);

  MyArray1[0] := 100;
  MyArray2[0] := 100;

  Value1 := PUInt64(@MyArray1)^;
  Value2 := PUInt64(@MyArray2)^;

  Value1 := PUInt64(@MyArray1[0])^;
  Value2 := PUInt64(@MyArray2[0])^;

  //Value1 := PUInt64(MyArray1)^;
  Value2 := PUInt64(MyArray2)^;
end;
```

In my understanding, the static array stores the value of the first element, second element, and so on. while the dynamic array store the address of the array.

Therefore, PUInt64(@MyArray2)^ will actually contain the address of the array in 64bit computer, and half of it contain the address in 32bit computer.

But why PUInt64(MyArray1)^ is an invalid cast?

Also it seems PUInt64(@MyArray2[0])^ is the safest cast since it works on both static and dynamic arrays. Is that correct?

Comment: Use `Value1 := PUInt64(MyArray1[0])^;` instead of Value1 := PUInt64(MyArray1)^;

Comment: @SchneiderInfosystemsLtd: That's not a good idea. `MyArray1[0]` is a `UInt64`, not a pointer to a `UInt64` (`100` is not a valid address). And in a 32-bit process, the sizes won't even match (pointer is 32 bit, but `MyArray1[0]` is 64-bit).

Comment: @Andreas Rejjbrand: Yes, you are right,The `PUInt64(MyArray1[0])^` is equal to `PUInt64(100)^`. That leads in a read access violation on address 0x064 (100).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First let me start by complimenting you for writing such a well-researched question!

Basically, it seems like you got most of it right. In Delphi, a static array is a value type, like a single integer or a record of integers. Using `sizeof` on any such variable, you get the full size of the data. On the other hand, a dynamic array is a reference type. The variable stores only a single pointer to the actual array data. So `sizeof` on a dynamic array yields only the size of the pointer.

Of course, this also affects what happens on assignments: if you copy a static array using `a := b`, you copy all the data, and end up with two independent arrays. If you copy a dynamic array, you only copy the pointer, and end up with two pointers to the same data.

So, back to your code:

```
Value1 := PUInt64(@MyArray1)^;
```

Yes, since `MyArray1` "is" the data that starts with `100`, `@MyArray1` is a pointer to the `100` value. The typecast is correct (since the data type in the array is `UInt64`, the type of a pointer to that value is `PUInt64`), and by dereferencing, you get `100`.

```
Value2 := PUInt64(@MyArray2)^;
```

Yes, since `MyArray2` is a pointer to the actual data, `@MyArray2` is a pointer to the pointer to the actual data. In a 64-bit process, pointers are 64-bit integers, so the typecast is valid. By dereferencing, you get back the original pointer to the actual data. But it is a bug to do this in a 32-bit process.

More simply, you could have written (*)

```
Value2 := NativeUInt(MyArray2);
```

Let's continue with

```
Value1 := PUInt64(@MyArray1[0])^;
```

This is easy: `MyArray1[0]` is your `100`, and you take the address and then dereference the pointer to get back the original value.

```
Value2 := PUInt64(@MyArray2[0])^;
```

Exact same reasoning here.

And

```
Value2 := PUInt64(MyArray2)^;
```

This is basically the case I mentioned above (at *), only dereferenced. It is valid in both 32-bit and 64-bit applications. (`PUInt64` is of native size because of the `P`; it may be 32-bit.) Indeed, `MyArray2` *is* a pointer to an `UInt64`, that is, a `PUInt64`, so by dereferencing it, you get that `UInt64` value (`100`).

However,

```
Value1 := PUInt64(MyArray1)^;
```

is a bug. `MyArray1` is, in your case, the exact same thing as a `UInt64`. It isn't a pointer to such a thing -- it isn't a `PUInt64`. Of course, you can lie to the compiler and tell it, "hey, treat this as a pointer to a `UInt64`". But by dereferencing it, you try to get the `UInt64` at address `100`, which will cause an access violation since you don't own that area in memory (most likely).

In a 64-bit process, the code compiles, since the sizes match. `PUInt64` has the size of a pointer (64 bits), and `MyArray1` has size 64 bits by your declaration.

In a 32-bit process, the code will not compile, since the sizes do not match. `PUInt64` has the size of a pointer (32 bits), but `MyArray1` has size 64 bits by your declaration.

> Also it seems PUInt64(@MyArray2[0])^ is the safest cast since it works
>   on both static and dynamic arrays. Is that correct?

Generally, I feel that static and dynamic arrays are two very different things, so I wouldn't attempt to force code to look the same in both cases.

Are you trying to get the first value in the array? If so, simply write `MyArray2[0]`. (Or `MyArray1[0]` in the static array case.) Are you trying to get the address of the first element? If so, I prefer `NativeUInt(MyArray2)` instead of `NativeUInt(@MyArray2[0])` (or `pointer`, or `PUInt64`). Indeed, if the array is empty, the first method yields `0` or `nil`, while the other is a bug.

**Update:**

To clarify, if `a` is a static array, the address to the first element is simply `@a` (or `@a[0]`). If `b` is a dynamic array, the address to the first element is `pointer(b)` (or `@b[0]`). You may cast any pointer to some other pointer-sized type, like `NativeUInt` (integer type) or `PUInt64` (specific pointer type) or `PCardinal` (specific pointer type) or ... . That will not change the actual value, only its compile-time interpretation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, which makes me understand this more clearly. Actually I hesitate to ask this question since it is not a complete real case. I encounter the problem in real case. Then I want to make further research on this instead of just letting my codes running. So I write the test snippet above to verify my opinions. What I need is just convert the array into a pointer and pass to a DLL written in C++. When casting using @ MyArray1, it is fine. But that does not work on @ MyArray2, finally I test with my test snippet and use PUInt64(@ MyArray2[0]).